# Shovelstrike Quarry - How does the game determine when the Quarry's reward sparkles?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

Shovelstrike Quarry's map icon sparkles occasionally, which grants potential extra bonus rewards, if accessed.

How does the game determine when this happens? For example, a set schedule, like the market rotation, or random. Also, if random, when/how does the game make the determination? For example, at the first time the game updates after animals move?

Note: an authoritative answer might involve reviewing the game's APK files, but perhaps observations might provide an answer, as well?